# Determining the hydrogen peroxide content in acetic acid

Tags: analytical-chemistry, concentration

For a project I have to determine the peroxide content in some samples, for which we plan to use glacial acetic acid. Unfortunately, I don't know the peroxide content of my acetic acid and because we need a high level of precision (0.1 ppm at least), this is important to know. So, I wanted to ask if you know how we could determine the peroxide content in our acetic acid.

Answer (score 1):

When you ask for a precision of 0.1 ppm, I assume you actually mean the detection limit?

A very common method for quantitative analysis of peroxide content is iodometric titration: the peroxides react with potassium iodide forming free iodine which is subsequently titrated with thiosulfate. It is basically at straight forward method, which only requires none or little preparation of the samples. But it is usually performed manually, and it could be a problem to obtain a DL of 0.1 ppm.

More sensitive methods (HPLC/fluorescence/spectrophotometric) methods requires on the other hand standard-curves made from samples with known content.

With the risk of being self-promotive, I can refer you to a recent review I have written about quantitative analysis of peroxoacetic acid [[1](https://doi.org/10/ggbpt8)].

Maybe you can find some inspiration and references there?

#### References

1. Sode, F. Analytical Methods for Peroxo Acids – a Review. *Anal. Methods* **2019**, 11 (27), 3372–3380. https://doi.org/10/ggbpt8. ([ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/334615125_Analytical_methods_for_peroxo_acids_-a_review_Frank_Sode))

Comment: why are you linking to Researchgate where one cannot actually read the article, rather than using the DOI to link to RSC?

Comment: Articles in RSC is behind a paywall and the first year after publication articles are under restriction to how they may be made publicly accessible by the author. But via Researchgate (or similar fora) I am permitted to send copies to anyone who asks.

Comment: Thank you @andselisk for the advice. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @FrankS No prob, I took a liberty to edit it a little for better readability and kept previous RG URL for those who use it.